# MONGODB Problem using sum but trying to access a string

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I am trying to sum cuisine.french, i know its a string so i feel that is where my problem is occurring and im not sure how to fix.
Here is examples of my collection below.  I am trying to sum the french cuisines in each borough.
Here is the line im running //
db.restaurants.aggregate([{ $group: { _id: "$borough", total: { $sum: "$cuisine.French"}}},{$sort: {total:-1}} ]);

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5fc3d933c6651d347aed3084"),
    "address" : {
        "building" : "323",
        "coord" : [
            -73.9538042,
            40.7730966
        ],
        "street" : "East   79 Street",
        "zipcode" : "10075"
    },
    "borough" : "Manhattan",
    "cuisine" : "French",
    "grades" : [
        {
            "date" : ISODate("2014-10-21T00:00:00Z"),
            "grade" : "A",
            "score" : 13
        },
        {
            "date" : ISODate("2014-03-19T00:00:00Z"),
            "grade" : "A",
            "score" : 4
        },
        {
            "date" : ISODate("2013-08-08T00:00:00Z"),
            "grade" : "A",
            "score" : 9
        },
        {
            "date" : ISODate("2013-01-22T00:00:00Z"),
            "grade" : "B",
            "score" : 17
        },
        {
            "date" : ISODate("2011-12-13T00:00:00Z"),
            "grade" : "A",
            "score" : 10
        }
    ],
    "name" : "Quatorze Bistro",
    "restaurant_id" : "40390046"
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5fc3d933c6651d347aed30b0"),
    "address" : {
        "building" : "0",
        "coord" : [
            -73.7889689,
            40.6433507
        ],
        "street" : "Intairp Arvl Bldg",
        "zipcode" : "11430"
    },
    "borough" : "Queens",
    "cuisine" : "French",
    "grades" : [
        {
            "date" : ISODate("2015-01-15T00:00:00Z"),
            "grade" : "Z",
            "score" : 21
        },
        {
            "date" : ISODate("2013-05-23T00:00:00Z"),
            "grade" : "A",
            "score" : 8
        },
        {
            "date" : ISODate("2012-05-14T00:00:00Z"),
            "grade" : "A",
            "score" : 0
        }
    ],
    "name" : "Air France Lounge",
    "restaurant_id" : "40391383"
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5fc3d933c6651d347aed30f3"),
    "address" : {
        "building" : "50",
        "coord" : [
            -73.95869990000001,
            40.780493
        ],
        "street" : "East   86 Street",
        "zipcode" : "10028"
    },
    "borough" : "Manhattan",
    "cuisine" : "French",
    "grades" : [
        {
            "date" : ISODate("2015-01-05T00:00:00Z"),
            "grade" : "Z",
            "score" : 18
        },
        {
            "date" : ISODate("2014-04-15T00:00:00Z"),
            "grade" : "B",
            "score" : 15
        },
        {
            "date" : ISODate("2013-09-09T00:00:00Z"),
            "grade" : "A",
            "score" : 7
        },
        {
            "date" : ISODate("2012-07-09T00:00:00Z"),
            "grade" : "A",
            "score" : 12
        }
    ],
    "name" : "Demarchelier Restaurant",
    "restaurant_id" : "40393303"
```

Comment: what do u want to achieve. try `$push`

Comment: Please post a sample of your collection's documents.

Comment: there are no french cuisines, what do you mean?#

Comment: this is only a few its a large amount so i just copied 3. There are cuisines with french.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$borough",
      total: {
        $push: {
          $cond: [
            {
              $eq: [
                "$cuisine",
                "French"
              ]
            },
            "$cuisine",
            "$$REMOVE"
          ]
        },
        
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $addFields: {
      total: {
        $size: "$total"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $sort: {
      total: -1
    }
  }
])
```

If you don't care about the rest of the documents, this should work too:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $group: {
      _id: {
        borough: "$borough",
        "cuisine": "French"
      },
      total: {
        $sum: 1
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $sort: {
      total: -1
    }
  }
])
```

Comment: It did perfectly thank you so much! and i see where i did wrong with the sum aspect so that you very much x2!